# How significatly less accurate is information we get from a 3 point scale rating system compared to a 5 scale rating system?

Tags: likert, rating

We are trying to add a rating system in our website and we are not sure whether to implement a 5 star rating system or a 3 scale(like,ok, don't like). The pro for the 3 point scale is that users would rate more often whereas the 5 star one would give us more granularity. How do we assess the quality of each?

Comment: (+1) According to your logic, a 7 point scale would be even better, and a 9 point scale even better than that, etc, because more points offer more "granularity." It might be a useful thought experiment to consider at what point this sequence gets to ridiculously large numbers--99? 1000001?--and *why* you think such numbers are too large.  There are both statistical and psychological considerations involved.